In Ruby's OpenSSL::PKey::RSA class, what does .to_s (aka .export) use as an initialization vector when it encrypts the private key?
This code returns an encrypted private key:
require 'openssl'

rsa_key_pair = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(2048)
public_key = rsa_key_pair.public_key
cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher::AES256.new(:CBC)
password = "Password12@"
private_key = rsa_key_pair.to_s(cipher, password)

Normally, when you use OpenSSL::Cipher::AES256 you have to provide the algorithm with both a key/password and an initialization vector, but private_key = rsa_key_pair.to_s(cipher, password) doesn't take an iv as an argument. What does it use as the iv, and/or what method can I use to decrypt the private key?

The code generates an encrypted private key in PKCS#1 format. This has a DEK-Info header with a hex string, which is the hex encoded 16 bytes IV.

Concerning decryption (tested for OpenSSL::OPENSSL_LIBRARY_VERSION: OpenSSL 3.0.13 30 Jan 2024): Derive a 32 bytes AES key via EVP_BytesToKey() (digest: MD5, iteration count: 1, salt: the first 8 bytes of the IV) using your password, then decrypt. The data behind the DEK-info header is the Base64 encoded ciphertext.
